# WSO2 API manager behind reverse proxy (Apache)

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to put the WSO2 API Manager 1.8.0 behind an Apache proxy but it does not work.
I modified `catalina-server.xml` and set `proxyPort` but it still redirects met to port 9443. Other pages (like `publish/`) redirect to localhost.
I also set the correct hostname (using `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>`) in `carbon.xml`.

I suspect there are some other configuration settings which must be changed. Is there an overview available with everything you need to change in order to put the API Manager behind a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

in catalina-server.xml you can set proxy port for http and https. so for management console you need to add proxyport for https as follow

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9443"
                **proxyPort="443"**
                bindOnInit="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
```

check this post on how publisher app site.json and store app site.json should be modified for reverse proxy.there you can set host name(your proxy) and even message contextpath.(this post explains with nginx same applicable to apache)

http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.in/2014/12/configure-wso2-api-manager-with-reverse.html